# Why Thread don't run?

Tags: android, java-threads

Adding breakpoints I can see that the Thread below is not executed.
I do the zipped search for ZIPCode using HTTP, returning a JSON, via viacep.com webservice.

```
if (code.length() == 8) {

    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Inicial.this, "",
                                "Loading ZipCode", true);
    dialog.show();
    new Thread() { // last BreakPoint stop here
        public void run() {
            try {
                //This code isn't running
                String url = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + code + "/json";
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                final HttpResponse resposta = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(resposta.getEntity()));
                            EditText endereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEndereco);
                            EditText compl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadComplemento);
                            EditText bairro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadBairro);
                            EditText cidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadCidade);
                            EditText uf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadUF);

                            endereco.setTag(obj.getString("logradouro"));
                            compl.setText(obj.getString("complemento"));
                            bairro.setText(obj.getString("bairro"));
                            cidade.setText(obj.getString("localidade"));
                            uf.setText(obj.getString("uf"));
                        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

So, the Loading Dialog is showing for undefined time because dialog.dismiss() is on the runOnUIThread. Anybody knows why this not working?

Comment: What's the stack trace say?

Comment: Thread thread = new Thread();

Comment: The try block isn't executed. @marcinj said I forgot "start", it's true :o

Comment: thread.start();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to call .start():

```
new Thread() { // last BreakPoint stop here
  //
}.start;
^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd load the Thread into a variable t and then you can run it's member methods on it like start(), join(), sleep, yield, interrupt, etc.

```
    Thread t = new Thread() { // last BreakPoint stop here
        public void run() {
            try {
                //This code isn't running
                String url = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + code + "/json";
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                final HttpResponse resposta = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(resposta.getEntity()));
                            EditText endereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEndereco);
                            EditText compl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadComplemento);
                            EditText bairro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadBairro);
                            EditText cidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadCidade);
                            EditText uf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadUF);

                            endereco.setTag(obj.getString("logradouro"));
                            compl.setText(obj.getString("complemento"));
                            bairro.setText(obj.getString("bairro"));
                            cidade.setText(obj.getString("localidade"));
                            uf.setText(obj.getString("uf"));
                        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
t.start();
```